# Python pandas, .apply, use multiple returned values

Tags: python, pandas

```
in[1]:  

import pandas as pd

    def somefunc(input1, input2):
        output1 = 1
        output2 = 2

        return [output1, output2]


d = {'col1': ['A1', 'B1'], 'col2': ['A2', 'B2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df[['col3', 'col4']] = df.apply(lambda x: somefunc(x['col1'], x['col2']), 
axis=1)

print df  

out[1]:  

   col1 col2  col3  col4
0   A1   A2     1     2
1   B1   B2     1     2
```

somefunc:
- Gets data from json in url with arguments input1 and input2 and puts it into a 
  new dataframe df2
- Creates output1, output2 with values from df2
- Deletes dataframe when output vaiables is calulated to save RAM

This executes perfectly, but I want to return 3 values which return an error

```
in[2]:  

import pandas as pd

    def somefunc(input1, input2):
        output1 = 1
        output2 = 2  
        output3 = 3


        return [output1, output2, output3]


d = {'col1': ['A1', 'B1'], 'col2': ['A2', 'B2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df[['col3', 'col4', 'col5']] = df.apply(lambda x: somefunc(x['col1'], x['col2']), 
axis=1)

print df  

out[2]:  
"ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"
```

The error is different from my actual program, but I guess it correlates;

```
KeyError: "['col3' 'col4' 'col5'] not in index"
```

Why does this work with one and two outputs but not three?
Python 2.7.14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is return `Series` from custom function:

```
def somefunc(input1, input2):
    output1 = 1
    output2 = 2  
    output3 = 3

    return pd.Series([output1, output2, output3])

d = {'col1': ['A1', 'B1'], 'col2': ['A2', 'B2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df[['col3', 'col4', 'col5']] = df.apply(lambda x: somefunc(x['col1'], x['col2']), axis=1)
print (df)
  col1 col2  col3  col4  col5
0   A1   A2     1     2     3
1   B1   B2     1     2     3
```

Or create `DataFrame` from `list`s by constructor:

```
def somefunc(input1, input2):
    output1 = 1
    output2 = 2  
    output3 = 3

    return [output1, output2, output3]

d = {'col1': ['A1', 'B1'], 'col2': ['A2', 'B2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df1 = df.apply(lambda x: somefunc(x['col1'], x['col2']), axis=1)
df[['col3', 'col4', 'col5']] = pd.DataFrame(df1.values.tolist())
print (df)
  col1 col2  col3  col4  col5
0   A1   A2     1     2     3
1   B1   B2     1     2     3
```

Answer (score 1):

You've stumbled upon a *shape mismatch* between the dataframe and the result.

If you'll note, in the first case, you have a dataframe of 2 columns, and your result is returned as a list of two items. You'll see the intermediate output is this:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     1     2
```

What pandas has done, is that it has *special cased* the return value, and *snapped* it into a dataframe of the same size as the input (it assumed that you wanted a dataframe because the shape of the result is the same). Since the result is a DataFrame in this case, you can assign it back.

With the second function, unfortunately, the number of elements returned in the list is *3*. This is *not* the same size as the original dataframe, so what is returned is a *single* column of lists.

```
0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [1, 2, 3]
dtype: object
```

Pandas does not know what to do with this data, and so does not do anything with it. Coincidentally, you cannot assign a Series object of lists to a dataframe slice, and so you get an error.

The solution here, is to *not* return a list, but instead return a `pd.Series` object.

```
def somefunc(input1, input2):
    return pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
```

This returns a dataframe as a result (pandas now smartly stacks each series to form a row in the final dataframe):

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
```

And assigning this is as easy as it was before.

Comment: @sinB You're welcome. Although if I were you, I'd be more appreciative of an answer that explains your error PLUS gives you code, instead of just a code based solution. ;)

Comment: You are right @COLDSPEED, newbie mistake.
Well, the answer has been chosen this time but I appreciate your effort just as much. next time ;)